# How to align tabs at bottom of screen in fragmenttabhost

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I want to align tabs on bottom of screen I tried to do this with relative layout using alignParentBottom 'true' but didn't get success. Can any one guide me?

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: Tabs should always be at the top in Android

Comment: I posted my code you just use it...I hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You just add this two lines into your tab widget that's all...

```
        <TabWidget
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to locate tabs at bottom, but if you need, hide android widget by weight=0 and work with your own "realcontent" FrameLayut

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_main_app_gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:background="#EAE7E1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23150258/2765497